# Fetch ignores "entity" designation - CoreData on iOS - returns wrong entity

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4, core-data

OK so I have two Entities in my CoreData model... they are both custom classes...

The first ManagedObject sub-class just has ONE variable, called "mm" ...

```
@interface length : NSManagedObject {
@private
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * mm;

@end

#import "length.h"
```

...

```
@implementation length
@dynamic mm;

@end
```

... ok the other ManagedObject sub-class is called "Times" and has a lot more variables but nothing weird.

OK I just have ONE managedObjectContext for the entire app.

I have three different objects that do fetches. They all have their own instance variables for the fetch stuff, the only thing that they share is the managedObjectContext itself and its persistentStoreCoordinator.

The problem is that the fetches for one Entity are returning arrays that contain the OTHER entity!!! BUT WHY?!?!

Look here is how I do my fetchRequests for the "length" class:

```
- (void)setUpLengths {
    NSLog(@"Setting up focal lengths");

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"length" inManagedObjectContext:MOC];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *myFetch = [MOC executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if(myFetch == nil) {
        //handle error
    }

    length *thisNewLength = nil;
    //thisNewLength = [[FocalLength alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:MOC]; (commented out this line to fix memory leak, but still had same problem when it was uncommented and released at the bottom of the method)
    int x;
    int l = [myFetch count];
    NSLog(@"lengths count: %i",l);
    for(x = 0; x < l; x++) {
        thisNewLength = [myFetch objectAtIndex:x];
        NSString *newEntry = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",thisNewLength.mm];
        if([thisNewLength.mm intValue])
            [main_view_controller addLength:newEntry];
        NSLog(@"Added FL: %@",newEntry);
    }
    [fetchRequest release]; 
}
```

...
and here is how I do it for the "Times" (table display):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)thisTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [thisTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    Time *time = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell withTime:time];

    //[CellIdentifier release];
    //fetchedResultsController = nil;

    return cell;
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Time" inManagedObjectContext:MOC];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSError *err;
    if(![MOC countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&err]) {
        //handle error
    }
    int count = [MOC countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&err]; 
    self.current_count = count;
    if(count == NSNotFound) {
        //Handle error
    }
    //NSLog(@"Times object count: %i", count);

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:MOC sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];

    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    //[fetchRequest release]; set to autorelease
    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    return fetchedResultsController;
}



- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] withTime:anObject];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)myTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//    Time *time = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//    selected_time = time; commented 7-11

    selected_time = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]; //more direct

    //fetchedResultsController = nil;
    doneButtonItem.title = @"Use";
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)myTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the managed object for the given index path
        Time *touched_time = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSNumber *slot = touched_time.slot;
        //NSLog(@"SLot: %@",slot);
        if(current_count < 6) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                                  initWithTitle:@"Improper Deletion"
                                  message:@"There must be at least five times." 
                                  delegate:nil 
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            self.doneButtonItem.title = @"Done";
        } else if([slot intValue] != -1) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                                  initWithTitle:@"Improper Deletion"
                                  message:@"You can't delete a time currently assigned to a main slot." 
                                  delegate:nil 
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            self.doneButtonItem.title = @"Done";
        } else {
            [MOC deleteObject:touched_time];
            // Save the context.
            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![MOC save:&error]) {
                /*
                 Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

                 abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
                 */
                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                abort();
            }
            --current_count;
            self.doneButtonItem.title = @"Done";
        }
        //fetchedResultsController = nil;
        //[slot release]; didn't alloc so why releasE?

    }   
}
```

..

SO WHY, when I add a new "length," does it show up as the first item in the "Time" table?! Please tell me, because I'm at my wits end here. Just when I thought I understood CoreData, it does some weird thing like this and has me thinking I must be insane. I have tried clean, clean folder, two different devices and simulator, same problem. Fetch request seems to be broken. How do I fix it?

Comment: Firstly you interface file above has `interface length : NSManagedObject`, then your implementation is for `FocalLength` - what's with that?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. It's not like that in the real versions.

Comment: You should follow the naming conventions. Entity and Class names start with uppercase so that `length` should be `Length`. Property names should be meaningful so expand `mm` to something that will make sense to others and yourself when you read the code a year from now.

Answer (score 1):

There is really only 3 causes:

(1) You have the entity for the `Length` class set improperly to the `Times` entity so that fetches of `Time` entity return `Length` objects.

(2) `Length` is a subentity of `Time` and the default fetch returns subentities so that a fetch against the `Time` entity will return all `Length` objects as well.

(3) When you create a new `Length` object, you actually do so against the `Time` entity.

The last is usually caused by mixing the use of custom subclasses and generic NSManagedObjects for the same entity, e.g:

At one point you do:

```
NSManagedObject *newLength=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Time" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

In any case, I would first look to the code where you create the new `Length` objects. If the problem is not in the data model i.e. (1) or (2) above, it will be there.

Answer (score 0):

You should try setting cacheName to nil in your fetchedresultscontroller initWithFetchRequest. I had a similar issue with the wrong entities being returned and that solved it.